# How to create a 2d vector in python

Tags: python, vector

I want to create a 2d vector in python and later add elements to it accordingly. I should also be able to retrieve the size of the vector in my code.

Comment: You should verily read [ask]. Your question history is quite bad. Read this article by *the mighty* [Jon Skeet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts): [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Finally, you should [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Use list of lists.

```
myL = []
for i in range(5):
   myL.append([i for i in range(5)])

for vector in myL:
    print(vector)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

For every element of the list `myL`, you can get the length using `len(myL[index])`, and can also append element to it using `myL[index].append(newelement)`. Example:

```
print(len(myL[2]))
# prints 5
myL[2].append(100)
print(len(myL[2]))
# prints 6
```